# Knockout JS will not update mapped object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm very new to Knockout JS. I haven't found much help through Google on mapping with knockout js. I have a JSON coming in from the server. I map the JSON with the knockout js mapping library. The data-binded dom associated with the property does not update. 
I have included a fiddle of the script im using. 
Notice the json object that gets mapped into the observable. When the load button is clicked, the json is mapped and the value of the property "test" is supposed to show up in the tag. Any ideas why its not showing up in the tag?

There is a working example in the JS fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/sLZmQ/

This is the JSON that is being mapped

```
 var json = {
"id": 9,
"test": "John Doe",
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Doe",
"referenceNumber": "BUY-08",
"position": "Buyer",
"type": "Buyer",
"telephone": "028 82 240780",
"email": "m@email.com",
"departmentId": 3,
"departmentName": "DEPT B",
"country": "United Kingdom"
};
```

My Example Script

```
var masterModel = function()
{
var self = this;
self.members = ko.observableArray([]);
self.websites = ko.observableArray([]);    
self.seoData = ko.observable();
self.test =  ko.observable();
self.loadWebsite = function(website)
{

var json = {
"id": 9,
"test": "John Doe",
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Doe",
"referenceNumber": "BUY-08",
"position": "Buyer",
"type": "Buyer",
"telephone": "028 82 240780",
"email": "m@email.com",
"departmentId": 3,
"departmentName": "DEPT B",
"country": "United Kingdom"
};

              self.test(ko.mapping.fromJS(json))
              console.log(self.test);


}    
}
    var master = new masterModel();

   ko.applyBindings(master);
```

The problem is when you click on the loadWebsite the $data.test.test is not updating!

Comment: Sorry what is not happening?  Is the fiddle your example code or somthing else?

Comment: The fiddle. The data-bind is not being updated.

Comment: Updated when/how?  What tiggers the update?  The fiddle looks correct

Comment: When you click on the load button. The data from the json is not showing up in the data-bind.

Comment: There's no 'load button' showing.

Comment: I see: "1. test outer 
1. test inner(test outer) 
2. test inner 2(test outer)" as the result

Comment: Hmmm thats strange. I made another fiddle. I copied it and added to this one. Sorry about that. http://jsfiddle.net/sLZmQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated and it seems to work with some minor changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/bYQu7/

Key point is I dereferenced the 'test' observable:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: test().test">?</h1>
```

And I also initialized the initial value:

```
self.test = ko.observable({ test: ko.observable('WTF') });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been trying to get this for 3 days now!

Comment: np,  BTW  I've found the mapping plugin not worth the hassle, unless you are doing some very exotic stuff.